# what is wrong with this code of login validate form using php

Tags: php, html, mysql

In this code login page is going to validate form and if password is correct then its working correct but if not then its not working else code why?
Here is code

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $user=$_POST['user'];
        $password=$_POST['password'];
        $query="select * from users where user='$user' and password='$password'";
        $run=mysqli_query($con,$query);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($run)>0){
            $row=mysqli_fetch_array($run);
            $u_name=$row['user'];
            $u_password=$row['password'];
            if($user==$u_name && $password==$u_password){
                if(isset($_POST['remember'])){
                    setcookie('user',$user,time()+60*60*7);
                    setcookie('password',$password,time()+60*60*7);
                }
                session_start();
                $_SESSION['user']=$user;
                echo "<script> window.location.assign('../index.php'); </script>";
                exit();
            }
            else{
                echo "<script> alert('incorrect user name or password')</script>";
                echo "<script> window.location.assign('login.php'); </script>"; 
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

`if` condition  part is working correctly but not `else` condition  part .help me please.

Comment: the security of this code is way off! use prepared statments with mysqli and never ever store passwords in plaintexts or even in cookies

Comment: your if condition does not make sense `if($user==$u_name && $password==$u_password)` you are querying with the same username and password and then checking it again.why?

Comment: @Akintunde  i had developed code in pdo form , in this way i am asking for my better understanding

Comment: The `else` in  your `if` statement will never occur because you already checking it from your query.

Comment: Please `indent` your code properly.

Answer (score 1):

The answer of your question is because you have the alert js inside the if statement where it will be executed only if there is more than 0 rows returned.

Please hash your users passwords.
Please use prepared statements to use with users input on DB query.
Echoing JS like that aint cool but its up to you if you want use it.

Answer (score 1):

Your `else` is in your first `if(mysqli_num_rows($run)>0) condition`.

That's why this is not working

correct code is

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $user=$_POST['user'];
        $password=$_POST['password'];
        $query="select * from users where user='$user' and password='$password'";
        $run=mysqli_query($con,$query);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($run)>0){
            $row=mysqli_fetch_array($run);
            $u_name=$row['user'];
            $u_password=$row['password'];
            if($user==$u_name && $password==$u_password){
                if(isset($_POST['remember'])){
                    setcookie('user',$user,time()+60*60*7);
                    setcookie('password',$password,time()+60*60*7);
                }
                session_start();
                $_SESSION['user']=$user;
                echo "<script> window.location.assign('../index.php'); </script>";
                exit();
            }
        }
        else{
            echo "<script> alert('incorrect user name or password')</script>";
            echo "<script> window.location.assign('login.php'); </script>"; 
        }
    }
?>
```